# Xcode 6.3.2 The application does not have a valid signature

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation, provisioning

I have tried every related thread and did all the suggested steps:

1. Remove All provisioning profiles
2. Create new app id

But I still get

> App Installation Failed, The application does not have a valid
>   signature

error when installing app on iPhone 6 iOS 8.3

This app was installing fine on this phone yesterday before I installed Parse & Facebook frameworks. Also other apps still install fine on this phone.

Comment: Just for anyone else having this issue. I tried every possible solution and ended up creating a new blank project and copy pasted my assets to make it work. I removed Embedded Binaries. And `#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>` is now only in bridging header and not imported in any swift files. While FBSDKCoreKit in not imported in bridging header but instead imported in every swift file it is needed. Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for anyone else having this issue. I tried every possible solution and ended up creating a new blank project and copy pasted my assets to make it work.

I removed Embedded Binaries. 
And `#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>` is now only in bridging header and not imported in any swift files.

While `FBSDKCoreKit` in not imported in bridging header but instead imported in every swift file it is needed.

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 1):

On xcode 8, I've fixed it by editing a line in the code (adding and then deleting a character anywhere in the code). Seems to be a Xcode 8 bug...

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem.

I installed the last update of OS X and my problem was fixed!

I hope that it can help you or someone!

My Xcode version: 7.3, using Swift and Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Xcode 8.1, I was able to fix this by deleting the app from my device, unplugging it from Xcode, and plugging it back in.